# Nuance of “Why” which has comma after it

Tags: word-choice, connotations

On Twitter, a phrase in an advertising was [mentioned as a mistake](https://mobile.twitter.com/ronanhand/status/1366657904292417545) by a native English speaker.

> Why, Subaru?

I think the advertising tries to say “Why don’t you choose Subaru?”
However, this sentence seems to sound wired to some people.
Some said the comma after why is unnecessary in their reply.
However, it doesn’t make sense to me. Could somebody tell me how “Why, Subaru?” sounds like?

Comment: It sounds like 'Why, Subaru, did you make this bad car?'. To suggest a purchase we would usually say 'Why not Subaru?'

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Let me clarify a bit. If we say ‘Why, somebody?”, it has the connotation that we are blaming him/her. Is it correct?

Comment: "Why, somebody?" doesn't necessarily mean that you're blaming someone.  It just means "Why did you do that, somebody?"  The reason for asking could be blame, confusion, or just simple curiosity.  It depends on context.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The comma makes it look like you are using [**direct address**](https://www.grammar-monster.com/lessons/commas_with_vocative_case.htm) (or "vocative case"). Quoting from the site that I have linked:

> When addressing a person or thing directly, the name used must be offset with a comma (or commas if it's mid-sentence).

So if Mary has done something and I want to know why, I could say,

> Why, Mary? Why did you do that?

Note that the comma separates the name of the person who is being asked the question.

Therefore, if you write "Why, Subaru?" then it looks like you are addressing the company named Subaru and asking them why they did something. In the tweet you link, the writer says:

> Why, SUBARU, couldn’t you pay a native English-speaking copywriter (or any native English speaker) to check your content before launch?

Here he is using **direct address** to ask Subaru a question.

If you want the meaning "Why should someone choose Subaru?" then you should *not* use a comma and just write **"Why Subaru?"** so that you are not putting it the form of direct address.

Comment: Your answer really help my understanding. Thank you so much.